# React Native: What is the best way to make a list of button elements given data from a Fetch(Url) request?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-button

I want to make a list of button elements that the user can tap. The amount of button elements will vary from 3 - 5 depending on the result of a fetch request that I do. I know how to populate a flatlist based on the result of a fetch request but not the contents of a button. Any help?

For example, [using this JSON](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json), suppose I wanted to render buttons for the amount of movies in there, each button having the name of the movie. The amount of movies will vary.

Comment: You want to render a list of botton and each button should have different onclick actions. Is that so.

Comment: Can you please share the list of data based on which you want to render the buttons.

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq I have edited my post to reflect a better example of the type of data I may use to render buttons.

Comment: why don`t you use flatlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the movies to a state after Api response like this.

```
this.setState({movies: apiResponse.movies})
```

```js
  

renderMovieList(){
    return  this.state.movies.map((movie, i, movieArray) =>
      <View 
        key={movie.id} 
        style={{ height:50, padding:20}}>
        <Button
          onPress={()=> this.handleOnPress(movie)}
          title={movie.title}
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  
  handleOnPress(movieDetails){
   alert(movieDetails.title);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor: "#0d98ba"}}>
        {this.state.movies.length? this.renderMovieList(): null}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[See full code here](https://github.com/rickyansari/LoginPinReactNative/blob/workingWithStringManipulation/src/screens/multipleButtons.js)

Answer (score 0):

**Fetching**

- Create api.
- Create function fetching in sagas
- Set index (sagas)
- Create redux reducer to get data from fetching
- In component mapping redux state to get data

**Make list items**

- Try render function use return ListItem
- It don't cluttered